# Aidl not found,but it already exists

Tags: android, linux, python-2.7, aidl

if i type in buildozer -v android release.and not in root.

#### Check that aidl can be executed

#### build-tools folder not found /home/m/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools

#### Search for Aidl

#### Aidl not found, please install it.

but if i type in aidl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB91B.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this error for a long time and multiple instances, even after trying to *`reinstall Aidl`*, *`reinstall buildozer`*, and *`deleting .buildozer project file`*.

**Problem**

This was caused by installation of `wrong/outdated/mixed` android-sdk build tools at;

*`~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools`*

Note: 
Buildozer can only build without Aidl error if only the latest/correct android-sdk build-tools are installed.

**Solution**

Navigate to *android-sdk build-tools* path as shown below;

*`cd ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools`*

Check the latest build tool you have, type;

*`ls`*

You should see a list of folders with names *`29.0.0`*, *`29.0.2`*, or any other folders.... this can be different. **Note the latest version**, eg (from example above is *`29.0.2`*)

If this folder is empty proceed.

Type;

*`sudo rm -Rf *`*

Then run the following command;

*`cd ~`*

On the command below, replace "build-tools;29.0.0" version flag with your latest version (Noted above from *`ls`* command). eg ("build-tools;29.0.0" to "build-tools;29.0.2"). Use the command as it is if the *`build-tools`* folder was empty.

Hit enter to download.

*`~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.0"`*

Navigate to your Buildozer build project folder, run;

*`buildozer android debug`*

I hope this will help you solve the problem.